# can someone help me to print this pattern in java or help me with the logic

Tags: java, numbers

```
    5
   54
  543
 5432
54321
```

I tried to print the pattern above using the following for loop but I don't know why it's not working,

```
for(int i = 0;i<=5;i++,count = 1,System.out.println()){
    for(int j = 5;j>=i;j--)
    {
        System.out.print("");
    }
    for (int k = 5;count <=i;count++,k--)
    {
        System.out.print(k+"");
    }
```

Comment: Hey there! Thanks for providing your code and your desired output. It's really useful to have those. If you wanted to make your question even better, you could *also* tell us what your code is currently doing, by showing us an example of its *current* output to go with your *desired* output :)

Comment: "enter code here" wont compile... printing and joining an empty string (`""`) is doing nothing (useful)

Comment: Poor title. Rewrite to summarize the central technical issue.

Answer (score 0):

You need something like this:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        int count = 0;
        for (int j = 5; j >= i; j--) {
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
        for (int k = 5; count <= i; count++, k--) {
            System.out.print(k);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
```

It prints:

```
    5
   54
  543
 5432
54321
```

Your mistakes:

> At `for(int i = 0;i<=5;i++,count = 1,System.out.println()){`
>   This is not a good place for: `count = 1,System.out.println()`
>
> At `System.out.print("");` This doesn't print anything.
>
> At `System.out.print(k+"");` the `+""` is not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you need to print pattern for string "54321" only:

```
public class Answer {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
    String line = "54321";
    for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
      System.out.format("%5s%n", line.substring(0, i));
    }
  }
}
```

However you can print any line with this triangular pattern:

```
public class Answer {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String alphabet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    printTriangle(alphabet);
    String digits = "9876543210";
    printTriangle(digits);
  }

  private static void printTriangle(String line) {
    int lineLen = line.length();
    for (int i = 1; i <= lineLen; i++) {
      System.out.format("%" + lineLen + "s%n", line.substring(0, i));
    }
  }
}
```